# Finding the complementary language of a given language

Tags: computational-complexity

I'm trying to figure out what's the complementary language of:

L = {w#w : w∈{a,b}<sup>*</sup>, |w| = k}

I think it's the language of all the words w#w where |w|!=k.

I think my answer is not correct. How should I think about this? And what is the correct answer?

Comment: It would be helpful to know what your exact definition of complementary definition is.

Comment: I don't know the formal definition, but as I can guess it would be: Lc = {a,b}*\L.

Comment: Is # a new symbol or does it just indicate concatenation?

Comment: The words that the DFA will accept are of the form `w#w` where |w| = k (and `#` is an actual symbol).

Comment: This is a frequent source of confusion. If $L\subseteq A^*$ for a finite set of symbols $A$, then the *complement* language $L^c$ is defined to be $A^*\setminus L$. However, it might be the case that the question meant by the *complementary* language all words of the form $x\#y$ that are not of the form $x\#x$, in which Dominik's answer is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Since L contains only words like $abb#abb$ with the property that they repeat themselves (with a "#" in the middle), words like $abb#bab$ where the second part is different from the first part will not be in your language.

Now it is easy to see that $$L^c=\{a\text{#}b|a\ne b, |a|=|b|=k\}$$ .

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So that would be **ALL** the words of the form w#w where |w|!=k **OR** w#z where w!=z?

Comment: Not exactly. See edit above.

Comment: But also words like w#w where |w|!=k will be there  (in L^c), or not?

Comment: **|a| or |b| is not k** instead of **|a|=|b|=k** will be correct too?